# How to write update query to update multiple fields in mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb

How to write this update query for updating a mongo record in c#.

```
db.collection.update({ "S_Id" : 110 },{ "Name" : "Name1","Batch" : "43","Date":"9/2/2011",  "Status" : 0 });
```

I'am trying like this

```
IMongoUpdate update = new UpdateDocument();
if (Named != null) { update = Update.Set("Name", "Name1"); }
if (Date != null) { update = Update.Set("Date", "18/02/2013"); }
if (Batch != null) { update = Update.Set("Batch",43); }
coll.Update(query, update);
```

was I'am doing correct or in what way i have to do it, please make me the correct way to proceed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example, you are potentially overwriting the value of `update` for each option, so will only be sending a single update command to `col1.Update()`.

you will want to use the `Update.Combine` method, something vaguely like this: (untested, and a bit ugly...)

```
    var updateValues = new List<UpdateBuilder>();
    if (Named != null) { updateValues.Add(Update.Set("Name", "Name1")); }
    if (Date != null) { updateValues.Add(Update.Set("Date", "18/02/2013")); }
    if (Batch != null) { updateValues.Add(Update.Set("Batch", 43)); }
    IMongoUpdate update = Update.Combine(updateValues);
    coll.Update(query, update);
```

Answer (score 0):

it has now modified to:

```
    FilterDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument> builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
    FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter;

    filter = builder.Eq("_id",BsonObjectId.Create(objectid));
```

// or field to search

```
    var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
 .Set("key1", "value1")
 .Set("key2", "value2")
 .CurrentDate("lastModified"); 

  Collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

Comment: This does not apply as the question specifically is about building an update over multiple lines. Your query works, it just does not answer the question.